# How to manipulate c# code programatically In .Net Core?

Tags: c#, code-generation

In .Net Core I want to manipulate .cs file. for example I want to add/remove/change methods.
Is there any library for doing this?

Example
I have Plugins.cs file as follow:

```
public class Plugins
{

    public static JToken GetPluginsList(JObject inputs, ControllerBase controlerBase)
    {
        // all plugins in repo
        return true;
    }

    public static JToken GetInstalledPluginsList(JObject inputs, ControllerBase controlerBase)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static JToken InstallPlugin(JObject inputs, ControllerBase controlerBase)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static JToken UnInstallPlugin(JObject inputs, ControllerBase controlerBase)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static JToken RemovePluginFromRepo(JObject inputs, ControllerBase controlerBase)
    {
        // some implementation
        return true;
    }

}
```

I need a some APIs to manipulate above code. i want to add new method for example or get the body of an existing method.

Anything like this:

```
somelib.GetMethodBody("RemovePluginFromRepo").Body
```

that returns:

```
// some implementation
return true;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is working and what not? Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think any *grammatical* operational on code would be a disaster, maybe you mean *programatically*

Answer (score 2):

C# is not a scripting language. It needs to be compiled prior to execution. So, while you can "programmatically" modify the contents of a .cs file or any other type of file, it won't make a difference as to how the executable runs/works. The only way to accomplish what you're asking - i.e. "add/remove/change methods" - would be by employing something called a delegate. You'd still have to pretty much create every possible method your program might need, but a delegate makes it so that you can pass methods as parameters, effectively accomplishing what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using an scripting engine to run theme at runtime. so the problem is code manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the functionality in the System.CodeDom namespace.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom

It might not be exactly what you expect, but perhaps it offers something useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;


SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);

MethodDeclarationSyntax method = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
    .First(m => m.Identifier.ToString() == "methodName");

method.Body.ToFullString();
```